# Check if the sets are linearly dependent or independent

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm going back to university soon and wanted to refresh. I've come across this question and have no idea how to start. Could someone help me please? Thank you!

> Let $[e_1, e_2, e_3]$ be an ordered basis of $\mathbb{R}^3.$ Consider the following lists of vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3.$ Which are linearly independent and which are linearly dependent? Justify your answers.
>
> $(i) S1 = [e_1, e_2 + 5e_3]$
>
> $(ii) S2 = [e_1 + 3e_2, 3e_1 + e_2 + 8e_3, 2e_1 + 5e_2 + 2e_3]$
>
> $(iii) S3 = [e_1 + 2e_2 − 3e_3, −2e_1 + 2e_2 − 5e_3, 4e_1 + 2e_2 − e_3]$

[workings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAtsX.jpg)
[2nd part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhJ0p.jpg)

Comment: Can you recall the definition of linearly dependency?

Comment: A finite set S = {x1, x2, . . . , xm} of vectors in R^n is said to be linearly dependent if there exist scalars (real numbers) c1, c2, . . . , cm, not all of which are 0, such that c1x1 + c2x2 + . . . + cmxm = 0.

Comment: Ok, so start by taking scalars $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,$ put them in front of each vector given, and see if the scalars must equal $0$ or not, using the basis given. By the way, $S1$ contains only two vectors?

Comment: Yeah, that was part of the question, I didn't know how to type this up what you said, so I've added a picture link! is this what you mean't. Its under the question.

Comment: Yes. Can you solve that system of equations?

Comment: I added a second image called 2nd part, is this how you read them off. I'm not sure how that allows me to prove they equal 0. Also how would you apply it to the question with only two vectors.

Answer (score 0):

I will prove $S_2$ is linearly independent, same method is used for $S1, S3.$

Let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3\in \mathbb{R},$ such that:

$$\lambda_1(e_1+3e_2)+\lambda_2(3e_1+e_2+8e_3)+\lambda_3(2e_1+5e_2+2e_3)=0$$

We know $[e_1,e_2,e_3]$ is a basis, so rearranging:

$$e_1(\lambda_1+3\lambda_2+2\lambda_3)+e_2(3\lambda_1+\lambda_2+5\lambda_3)+e_3(8\lambda_2+2\lambda_3)=0$$

Placing in matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 3 & 2 \\
    3       & 1 & 5 \\
    0       & 8 & 2
\end{bmatrix}

After elementary operations, we find the coefficients must be $0,$ which means $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=0,$ so $S2$ is linearly independent.

Comment: thank you so much, by elementary operations do you mean that you made the matrix into all 0s

Comment: @abbiemosley Not all of it obviously, but using Gauss elimination to get it to Row Echelon Form.

Comment: was the final stage correct?

Comment: @abbiemosley Yes, it is.

Comment: @Itay4 thank you so much. Just wondered for the first on even, though it only has two vectors can you still use this technique

Comment: @abbiemosley You can, but that would be unnecessary. You can see right away they are linearly independent  as the first is represented by $e_1$ and the second by $e_2,e_3.$

Comment: @Itay4 perfect thank you, i'm assuming that S3 isn't linearly independent. so after you create the matrix, how would you state or word it to show that it is not

Comment: @abbiemosley Well, after reducing the matrix, you will have one free variable, which means there are infinite solutions to the equation, so the trivial solution is not the only one. One can conclude that the coefficients don't have to be $0,$ and the vectors are linearly dependent.

Comment: @Itay4 so the edit is my workings on trying the reduced matrix. Im not 100 percent sure if i've done it correctly to justify saying it isnt linear